# How to list contacts for Alexa for Business?

Tags: go, alexa-for-business

I'm using the AWS Alexa for Business Go SDK and while there are functions for `CreateContact`, `DeleteContact`, `GetContact`, `SearchContacts`, there isn't a function for `ListContacts` while there are List APIs for other objects `ListConferenceProviders`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/alexaforbusiness/

How can one get a list of contacts for Alexa for Business?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there isn't a `ListContacts` API, the `SearchContacts` API can be used with an empty filter slice in [`SearchContactsInput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/alexaforbusiness/#SearchContactsInput) as follows:

```
resp, err := svc.SearchContacts(
    &alexaforbusiness.SearchContactsInput{})
```

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/alexaforbusiness/#AlexaForBusiness.SearchContacts

For testing purposes, it will also work to have a `Filter` with an empty `Values` slice, even if `Key` is populated.